# How to retrieve the date format for a locale

Tags: java, date, locale, date-format

I've been using [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to format dates, but now I need to pass the format for the locale to the jQuery Date widget. How can I get the format?

**Update**:

To clarify, I need to get the pattern **in Java** so I can output it elsewhere. e.g. in some JavaScript where I might want to create a string like this with the date format in it:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({'dateFormat':'dd/mm/yy'})
```

Comment: which jquery date widget? What's your current code? The question is unclear.

Comment: you want the format strings like: "MM/dd/yyyy" or "dd.MM.yyyy", right?

Comment: @Bozho the particular widget is irrelevant. I need to get the format in Java so I can pass it to the JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the date pattern by using

```
((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK)).toPattern()
```

or if you just need the date

```
((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK)).toPattern()
```

API: [SimpleDateFormat.toPattern()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toPattern%28%29), [DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28%29), [DateFormat.getDateInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance%28int%29)

Second question is how to convert that to jQuery specific format pattern.

[Java date formatting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). vs [jQuery DatePicker Date Formatting](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)

- day of year in java D, in jQuery o
- short year in Java yy, in jQuery y
- long year in Java yyyy, in jQuery yy
- Month without leading zeros in Java M, in jQuery m
- Month with leading zeros in Java MM, in jQuery mm
- Month name short in Java MMM, in jQuery M
- Month name long in Java MMMM in jQuery MM
  -

Comment: That implies, that you really get a SimpleDateFormat object. Is this always the case?

Comment: Thanks, short format makes more sense in this context so I amended your answer.

Comment: @Puce This it the case in Apache Harmony at least. I'd venture a guess that this is true for other versions as well. Though this shouldn't be relied upon. DateFormat implementation: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/harmony/enhanced/java/trunk/classlib/modules/text/src/main/java/java/text/DateFormat.java?view=markup

Comment: I don't think that this is safe. You are casting to an implementation detail of the JRE. The JRE can change the class used to implement DateFormat.getDateInstance at any time causing a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking at this recently and haven't found an easy way to find this out using the standard library.  I require this to localise the Wicket class `org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.DateTextField`, which takes a SimpleDateFormat pattern rather than a DateFormat object. Here is the code I finally decided to use, it doesn't rely on the implementation details of the JVM but has to parse the output of the DateFormat.format for a particular date (11/22/3333 - in US format).

```
public static String simpleDateFormatForLocale(Locale locale) {
    TimeZone commonTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(commonTimeZone);
    c.set(3333, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 22);

    DateFormat localeDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    localeDateFormat.setTimeZone(commonTimeZone);
    String dateText = localeDateFormat.format(c.getTime());

    return dateText.replace("11", "MM").replace("22", "dd").replace("3333", "yyyy").replace("33", "yyyy");
}
```

In my case I want to force the use of `yyyy` even if the format returns a two digit year.  That is why I call `replace` for the year twice.

Here is the output for some sample locales:

```
en_US  11/22/33  MM/dd/yyyy
en_CA  22/11/33  dd/MM/yyyy
zh_CN  33-11-22  yyyy-MM-dd
de     22.11.33  dd.MM.yyyy
ja_JP  33/11/22  yyyy/MM/dd
```

If anyone can improve on this I would love to see their solution.

Comment: +1 for implementation independent solution. With a bit of extra work this could be made to support hours, minutes, etc. You could replace the year with `.replaceAll("33(33)?", "yyyy")` or similar to define the rule only once.

Comment: In what way is this implementation independent?

Comment: @Sam this is implementation independent because it does not depend on the implementation class returned by `DateFormat.getDateInstance` only on its public contract/interface.  There is no guarantee that all JVMs will use `SimpleDateFormat` to implement this, and even the ones that do could change their implementation.